# How to mimic the "desktop slideshow" feature in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, desktop, desktop-customization, slideshow

I've been using the Windows 7 RTM lately, and I love the new "desktop slideshow" feature that changes the desktop background at an interval. How can I mimic this behavior on other version of Windows? (I'm on Vista 64-bit, if it matters.) I don't need fancy transitions or other features, I just want it as close as possible to the Windows 7 feature without using up too many resources.

Comment: It is simple enough to do a search for "desktop slideshow" or "wallpaper switcher."

Comment: It's simple enough to do Google anything, but if you'd Google everything you wouldn't ask anything on SuperUser.

Comment: he_the_great: "Are you new to the stackoverflow family of websites? RTFM and Google it are not acceptable answers here."

Comment: @Joshhunt, that is why I didn't answer. There are tons of programs that fit the requirements for, "changes wallpaper." If there was actually some restricting factor on requirements it would be worth answering.

@Xenorose, not everything is easy to Google.

Comment: @he_the_great: My requirement is that it's almost identical to the Windows 7 feature. And yes, I could do a Google search (in fact I did), but there are so many results to choose from that I thought it would be better to ask here than to try each one.

Comment: @he_the_great, first, there's nothing like a good advice from people who already tried, again that's the point of SuperUser.
Also, there are a few restriction in this question: that it will be light on resources and minimalistic, that it will run in Vista etc'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try either [John's Background Switcher](http://www.johnsadventures.com/software/backgroundswitcher/), [WallPapa](http://www.phoeniixz.net/software.html) or [Wallpaper Juggler](http://www.codeplex.com/juggler/).

The cool thing is that they can not only cycle through pictures on your computer, but also download pictures from different sites, like [interfacelift](http://interfacelift.com) or [flickr](http://flickr.com).

Comment: Wallpaper seems to be exactly what I want. Thanks. :)

Comment: When I said Wallpaper I meant WallPapa. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Webshots from about Win98, in fact, I still use the same old version from back when (works even under Vista/Win7).
More modern programs don't offer anything new that I'd care for, all I want is a background change every set interval.
It simple, minimalistic and works well.

[Link to the old version (v. 1.3.0.2991)](http://www.mediafire.com/?znkyzgl3imn)

[Webshots Website](http://www.webshots.com/)

*They just don't make 'em like they used to.*

Answer (score 0):

I used the free version of wallpaper master for a long time under xp before going the pro version to take advantage of the dual monitor functions. http://jamesgart.com/wallpaperchanger/