# How can I get Windows 7-like alternating wallpapers in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, desktop-customization

In Windows 7, there is a theme of wallpapers which will be alternated once a few minutes. For example, in the Control Panel » Personalize, I can choose the "Nature" theme, then the wallpaper will be changed once in a few minutes.

How can I do this in Windows XP, possibly with the help of some external tools?

Comment: This question drifts into a seemingly endless list of answers. Have you tried to find some tools yourself?

Comment: Google is you friend try it search there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XP wallpaper rotater](http://superuser.com/questions/36034/xp-wallpaper-rotater) and/or [Application to minic the “desktop slideshow” feature in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/27519/application-to-minic-the-desktop-slideshow-feature-in-windows-7/27525)

Answer (score 1):

I use [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) for that, among other things:

> Configure the timer to have DisplayFusion change your wallpaper images automatically,

http://www.displayfusion.com/Features/Wallpaper/

Answer (score 0):

I use [Wallpaper Slideshow LT](http://www.gphotoshow.com/wallpaperss.htm). It has many features and settings. Click on tray icon to change the current wallpaper.